# Old xampp folder can't be deleted, xampp no working

Tags: xampp

I uninstalled xampp and installed a newer version with the latest 5.4 php on Windows. When i tried to install the new version of php, the old folder in C://xampp would delete. I deleted everything from that folder except memcached which I can't delete beacuse someone else is using it. So i installed the new xampp version in xampp54 folder.

When i installed the new xampp version, i get this errors for mysql

```
Expected Path: "c:\xampp54\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
MySQL Service detected with wrong path
Change XAMPP MySQL and Control Panel settings or
Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
Found Path: C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini     mysql
Expected Path: c:\xampp54\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=c:\xampp54\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql
```

When i try starting apache, i doesn't do anything. Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: I meant the latest 5.4 version, not latest php version

Comment: HAve you previosuly installed mysql as a service?

Comment: i just uninstalled xampp and installed newer version. nothing more. the 'xampp' folder of the old version can't be deleted so i installed it in 'xampp54'. that's it.

Comment: And it's not just mysql that is the problem. Apache won't start.

Comment: CAn you start apache and mysql from the original xampp?

Comment: no, i uninstalled the original xampp but the folder remained and i can't delete it beacuse of memcached. it says that memcached is still running somewhere but i don't know where and how to stop it

Comment: Put in the run box `services.msc` and see if its not there.

Answer (score 11):

Go to Task Manager Processes tab

- search MySql and click
- then click End task

After that, you can delete Xampp folder.

Answer (score 2):

I found memcached in the services and disabled it and it all works. Lesson of the day: Install xampp in 'xampp' folder, not 'xampp_me' or 'myxampp' beacuse it seems that both apache and mysql rely on them being installed in 'xampp' folder.

Answer (score 2):

I have same issues with you. But this worked perfectly with me.

Go to task manager, look for details, and search for the items that denies for deleting the folder. (mine is the php) then end task. You can now delete the xampp folder.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Stop the services: mysql and apache

   `Start > Run > Services.msc`
2. Kill the process 'Xampp Controller' from the Task Manager

   In my case, the services were stopped and removed automatically when I 
   uninstalled the Xampp. So, killing 'Xampp Controller' process worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

To delete the C://xampp old folder we need to stop the mysql service. To stop it, go to start -> run -> type services.msc. Search for mysql & apache and right click & stop. Then you would be able to delete the C://xampp folder.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me: Use the command line (if on Windows) Enter this into the terminal:

```
rmdir /Q /S none-empty-dir
```

(e.g. `C:\xampp`)

See: https://www.windows-commandline.com/delete-directory-from-command-line/

Comment: Does not work for me. I still get the message "The directory is not empty."

Answer (score 0):

This is worked

Go to resource monitor -> associated handle and  search the folder  you want to delete and end process

Answer (score 0):

You can try closing the FireZilla server also. In my case I closed the mysql and apache server but the folder couldn't be deleted. Later I found that the FireZilla server was running which was blocking the deletion of the xammp folder.